# Problems with javascript code in JSP?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am trying to get button value by clicking on the button in a jsp form. But for some reason when I click on the buttons it always displays "1". So, what could I be doing wrong? I am still learning Javascript and I implemented a small script to display the button value when I click on it. I feel that I am making a mistake in my Javascript code. Please help me out.

JSP page:-

```
<table
            <tr>
                <td colspan=4 align="center"
                    style="background-color:teal">
                    <b>User Record</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color:lightgrey;">
                <td><b>Record Number: </b></td>
                <td><b>Card Number: </b></td>
                <td><b>MiddleName:</b></td>
                <td><b>BankAccountID:</b></td>
                <td><b>CurrencyID:</b></td>
                <td><b>DayTransactionLimit:</b></td>
                <td><b>Select:</b></td>


</tr>
  <%
      if(request.getParameter("mobilenumber")!=null)
      {        
 FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File(("C:\\Users\\Surajitdas\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Demo\\records.txt")));
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
  String line = null;
  int count =0;
//  out.println("<table>");

  while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    //out.print(line + "<br/>");
      out.println("<tr>");
            count ++;

    String[] data = line.split("\t");
    for (String val : data) {

        out.println("<td>" + val + "</td>");


  }

  out.println("<td><input type =\"button\" id=\"getid\" onclick=\"getbuttonid()\" value=\"" + count + "\"></td>");
  }  
  out.println("");
  br.close();



      }

%>

  </table>          






</table

  <script type="text/javascript">
var MenuBar1 = new Spry.Widget.MenuBar("MenuBar1", {imgRight:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarRightHover.gif"});
function getbuttonid(){
    var id = document.getElementById('getid').value;
    alert(id);
}

</script>
```

Complete code of the JSP page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>HomePage</title>
<script src="JavaScript/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="styles/SpryMenuBarVertical.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>


<ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarVertical">
  <li><a href="#">Update Limit</a></li>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Delink Account</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Edit CardNumber</a>

  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Linked Accounts</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">SMS Alerts</a>
  <li><a href="#">Join Account</a>


</ul>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>


  <hr />
<hr />
<form>
  <p>
          Client Details
  <hr />
  <hr />
  </p>
  <p>Mobile Number:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="mobilenumber" id="mobilenumber" /> 
    </label>

  </p>
<p>Country:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="country" id="country"  /> 
    </label>

  </p>

<input type="submit" formaction="Search" formmethod="post" name="New" id="New" value="Search" />





  <p> Title:-
    <input type="text" name="Title" id="Title" value='Mr' />
  </p>
  <p>Middle Name:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="MiddleName" id="Middle Name" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>Address:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="address" id="address" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>City:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="City" id="City"value='AWENDO'/>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>Type of ID:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="Idtype" id="Idtype" value='Driving License' />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>Elma ID:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="elmaid" id="elmaid" value='1916507095'/>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>First Name:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value='Pramod1' />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>Last Name:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="LastName" id="LastName" value='Sahoo'/>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>Registration Branch:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="registrationbranch" id="registrationbranch" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>Email address:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="emailid" id="emailid" value='Pramodk@CS.com' />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>ID No:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="idno" id="idno" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <hr />
<hr />
  <p>
          Account Details
  <hr />
  <hr />
  </p>

  <p>Bank A/C id :- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="accountid" id="accountid"value='001001000095' />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>Transaction Limit:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="transactionlimit" id="transactionlimit" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>Currency:- 
    <input type="text" name="currency" id="currency"value='KES'/>
  </p>
  <p>Daily Limit:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="dailylimit" id="dailylimit" value='500000.0000'/>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit"formaction="Connectioncheck" formmethod="post"name="Update" id="Update" value="Update" />
  </p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <hr />
  Account List
  <hr />



  <table
            <tr>
                <td colspan=4 align="center"
                    style="background-color:teal">
                    <b>User Record</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color:lightgrey;">
                <td><b>Record Number: </b></td>
                <td><b>Card Number: </b></td>
                <td><b>MiddleName:</b></td>
                <td><b>BankAccountID:</b></td>
                <td><b>CurrencyID:</b></td>
                <td><b>DayTransactionLimit:</b></td>
                <td><b>Select:</b></td>


</tr>
  <tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>kenya</td>
<td>K</td>
<td>432342423</td>
<td></td>
<td>100000.0000</td>
<td><input type ="button" id="getid" onclick="getbuttonid()" value="1"></td>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>kenya</td>
<td>Kumar11</td>
<td>78788787878</td>
<td>OOOPP</td>
<td>100000.0000</td>
<td><input type ="button" id="getid" onclick="getbuttonid()" value="2"></td>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>kenya</td>
<td>Kb1</td>
<td>001001000095</td>
<td>KES</td>
<td>500000.0000</td>
<td><input type ="button" id="getid" onclick="getbuttonid()" value="3"></td>



  </table>          






</table


  <hr />
  Behind the Scene
  <hr />







  <p>Created By:-
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="createdby" id="createdby" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>Created On:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="createdon" id="createdon" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>Modified By:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="modifiedby" id="modifiedby" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>Modified On:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="modifiedon" id="modifiedon" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>Supervised By:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="supervisedby" id="supervisedby" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>Supervised On:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="supervisedon" id="supervisedon" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
      <input type="submit" name="Add" id="Add" value="Add" formmethod="post" formaction="AddController" />
    <input type="submit" name="Edit" id="Edit" value="Edit" formmethod="post" formaction="EditController" />
    <input type="submit" name="Save" id="Save" value="Save" />
   <input type="submit" name="Cancel" id="Cancel" value="Cancel" />
  <input type="submit" name="Recreate Key" id="Recreate Key" value="Recreate Key" />

    <input type="submit" name="Reset Password" id="Reset Password" value="Reset Password" />




  </p>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var MenuBar1 = new Spry.Widget.MenuBar("MenuBar1", {imgRight:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarRightHover.gif"});
function getbuttonid(){
    var id = document.getElementById('getid').value;
    alert(id);
}

</script>
```

Comment: could you run again your application, open the jsp you are talking about and copy it's full contents here?(via your browser's "View Page Source") thanks! your javascript code is correct, it might be that the variable count's value is really actually "1"

Comment: @OmasuPlus:- I have added the whole code of the JSP page. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notes for you: 1) ID is for a single element only in the html markup(your buttons all have the same id "getid" and this should not be done), use class if you want to assign a single name/targeting string to multiple elements

2)you can use **this** in the html markup to target the element the function is assigned to, check the code that i updated to fully understand what im blabbering about

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>HomePage</title>
<script src="JavaScript/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="styles/SpryMenuBarVertical.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>


<ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarVertical">
  <li><a href="#">Update Limit</a></li>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Delink Account</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Edit CardNumber</a>

  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Linked Accounts</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">SMS Alerts</a>
  <li><a href="#">Join Account</a>


</ul>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>


  <hr />
<hr />
<form>
  <p>
          Client Details
  <hr />
  <hr />
  </p>
  <p>Mobile Number:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="mobilenumber" id="mobilenumber" /> 
    </label>

  </p>
<p>Country:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="country" id="country"  /> 
    </label>

  </p>

<input type="submit" formaction="Search" formmethod="post" name="New" id="New" value="Search" />





  <p> Title:-
    <input type="text" name="Title" id="Title" value='Mr' />
  </p>
  <p>Middle Name:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="MiddleName" id="Middle Name" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>Address:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="address" id="address" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>City:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="City" id="City"value='AWENDO'/>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>Type of ID:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="Idtype" id="Idtype" value='Driving License' />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>Elma ID:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="elmaid" id="elmaid" value='1916507095'/>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>First Name:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value='Pramod1' />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>Last Name:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="LastName" id="LastName" value='Sahoo'/>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>Registration Branch:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="registrationbranch" id="registrationbranch" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>Email address:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="emailid" id="emailid" value='Pramodk@CS.com' />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>ID No:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="idno" id="idno" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <hr />
<hr />
  <p>
          Account Details
  <hr />
  <hr />
  </p>

  <p>Bank A/C id :- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="accountid" id="accountid"value='001001000095' />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>Transaction Limit:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="transactionlimit" id="transactionlimit" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>Currency:- 
    <input type="text" name="currency" id="currency"value='KES'/>
  </p>
  <p>Daily Limit:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="dailylimit" id="dailylimit" value='500000.0000'/>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit"formaction="Connectioncheck" formmethod="post"name="Update" id="Update" value="Update" />
  </p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <hr />
  Account List
  <hr />



  <table
            <tr>
                <td colspan=4 align="center"
                    style="background-color:teal">
                    <b>User Record</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="background-color:lightgrey;">
                <td><b>Record Number: </b></td>
                <td><b>Card Number: </b></td>
                <td><b>MiddleName:</b></td>
                <td><b>BankAccountID:</b></td>
                <td><b>CurrencyID:</b></td>
                <td><b>DayTransactionLimit:</b></td>
                <td><b>Select:</b></td>


</tr>
  <tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>kenya</td>
<td>K</td>
<td>432342423</td>
<td></td>
<td>100000.0000</td>
<td><input type ="button" id="getid" onclick="getbuttonid(this)" value="1"></td>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>kenya</td>
<td>Kumar11</td>
<td>78788787878</td>
<td>OOOPP</td>
<td>100000.0000</td>
<td><input type ="button" id="getid" onclick="getbuttonid(this)" value="2"></td>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>kenya</td>
<td>Kb1</td>
<td>001001000095</td>
<td>KES</td>
<td>500000.0000</td>
<td><input type ="button" id="getid" onclick="getbuttonid(this)" value="3"></td>



  </table>          






</table


  <hr />
  Behind the Scene
  <hr />







  <p>Created By:-
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="createdby" id="createdby" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>Created On:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="createdon" id="createdon" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>Modified By:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="modifiedby" id="modifiedby" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>Modified On:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="modifiedon" id="modifiedon" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>Supervised By:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="supervisedby" id="supervisedby" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>Supervised On:- 
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="supervisedon" id="supervisedon" />
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
      <input type="submit" name="Add" id="Add" value="Add" formmethod="post" formaction="AddController" />
    <input type="submit" name="Edit" id="Edit" value="Edit" formmethod="post" formaction="EditController" />
    <input type="submit" name="Save" id="Save" value="Save" />
   <input type="submit" name="Cancel" id="Cancel" value="Cancel" />
  <input type="submit" name="Recreate Key" id="Recreate Key" value="Recreate Key" />

    <input type="submit" name="Reset Password" id="Reset Password" value="Reset Password" />




  </p>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function getbuttonid(el){
    alert(el.value);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have one question and it's just for my curiosity. If  I want to pass the value = el.value to a integer variable inside a jsp tag by clicking on the button, how should I go about it?

Comment: var i = parseInt(el.value);

Comment: Is it possible to send var i to an integer variable inside a JSP tag? Java does execute on the server side while javascript executes on the client side. So, it looks kinda difficult .

Comment: i dont get your question.. sorry, if this is what you mean <% %> then no you cant as what you have said, javascript=client side and java=server